# How to find different between two times with sql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table contain reference time and a user check-in time. Both data is different in type.

Sample data

- `dtime` = 2023-06-02 08:23:21
- `work_time` = 08:00-18:00

And my code is...

```
SELECT substring(dtime,-8,5) AS chkin, 
SUBSTRING(work_time, 1, 5) AS wt1, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, substring(dtime,-8,5), SUBSTRING(work_time, 1, 5)) AS min_diff 
FROM ta_db 
WHERE id = 13181;
```

As a result...

- `chkin` = 08:23
- `wt1` = 08:00

Now, I want to know how many minutes different from `chkin` and `wt` with `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.
So I did this...

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, substring(dtime,-8,5), SUBSTRING(work_time, 1, 5)) AS min_diff
```

But it returns `NULL`. Please be advised.

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input data and expected output?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: why not just subtract the two columns from each other, plus watch the input to the [`timestampdiff()'](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php) function

Comment: @zhiguang can you show me please?

Comment: @lemon I'm using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @dtime = '2023-06-02 08:28:21';
SET @work_time = '08:00-18:00';

SELECT substring(@dtime,-8,5) AS chkin, 
SUBSTRING(@work_time, 1, 5) AS wt1, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @dtime, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@dtime, 1,10), ' ', SUBSTRING(@work_time, 1, 5))) AS min_diff
```

Comment: SELECT substring(dtime,-8,5) AS chkin, 
SUBSTRING(work_time, 1, 5) AS wt1, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, dtime, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(dtime, 1,10), ' ', SUBSTRING(work_time, 1, 5))) AS min_diff
from ta_db
WHERE id = 13181;

Comment: I adapted your code into the usable query on my script and it's working! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

my solution is to cast using `time()`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(dtime,-8,5) AS chkin, 
SUBSTRING(work_time, 1, 5) AS wt1, 
timediff(time(SUBSTRING(dtime,-8,5)),time(SUBSTRING(work_time,1, 
5))) AS min_diff 
FROM ta_db 
WHERE id = 13181;
```

Comment: You should not use subtraction between time(), because mysql converts to integer, your example worked because 08:00:00 and 08:23:00 converts to 80000 and 82300, resulting in 2300, which you divided by 100. But if the time was 10:00:00 and 08:23:00, it would convert to 100000 and 82300, which would result in 17700, dividing by a 100, 177, but the correct result is 97 minutes, you should use `timediff()`

Comment: edited as per your suggestion

Comment: Now the abs function will still convert to integer, timediff returns like this: `00:28:00`, on second thought i think that the TIMESTAMPDIFF is more appropriate for this